# How to add p# to a table using functional amend?

Tags: kdb

I have a query that returns data for a bunch of syms for a date from a table.

```
dataFromTab:delete date from select from table where date=2015.01.01,any (sym like) each ("sym1";"sym2";"sym3";"sym4")
dataFromTab:`sym xasc dataFromTab;
@[`dataFromTab;`sym;`p#];
```

type var is 98h and sorting by sym is working fine but when adding p# using functional amend is giving me a 'type error.

Any inputs on where i am going wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling all of this from within a function or from the global namespace?

If dataFromTab is a local variable then applying the `p# to the global reference`dataFromTab will not work.

```
q){data:select from tab;@[`data;`sym;`p#]}[]
'type
 [1]  {data:select from tab;@[`data;`sym;`p#]}
                         ^
q))\
```

You will need to reassign dataFromTab locally for this to work;

```
q){data:select from tab;data:@[data;`sym;`p#]}[]
```

You could also use 'set' to create your table globally, which would allow your original syntax to work. However you probably do not want to create unnecessary globals;

```
q){`data set select from tab;@[`data;`sym;`p#]}[]
`data
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I was making the mistake you pointed out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is `sym` a string column? I get that error if I convert to string:

```
q)trades:update string sym from trades
q)trades:`sym xasc trades
q)@[`trades;`sym;`p#]
'type
  [0]  @[`trades;`sym;`p#]
       ^
```

Can you try converting it to a symbol and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks. I am using a non reserved variable name to store it. I changed the name for simplicity here. Maybe I should edit the original post.

Comment: Amended my answer.

Comment: This particular code of mine is looped through for multiple dates. When i run this query in isolation it works. But it errors out with 'type when applied within the loop.

Comment: No. It is a sym column and i am trying to pick out certain kind of syms that match the criteria for eg where sym like "sym1*"